# Select no duplicate records from temp table by maxdate column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a result from temp table (as below from stored procedure) and I'd like to pull out from this temp table only records with maximum `stage_dt` which will remove dups in client list. `rownum` column is identity. How can I select from this temp table only records with maximum dates in column `stage_dt`?

```
lname     fname   RO#      fow_visit   stage_dt                 T_Stage  status  rownum
ADINYIRA  DELA    09-0373  2011-10-06  2010-09-28 17:02:30.460           Y       6
ADINYIRA  DELA    09-0373  2011-10-06  2009-10-08 12:50:33.007  T2       Y       7
APPELLO   CAROL   08-0493  2011-04-13  2011-04-08 12:48:31.310           Y       40
APPELLO   CAROL   08-0493  2011-04-13  2008-10-13 18:20:49.210  4        Y       41
BLACK     ERMA    10-0054  2011-10-06  2010-02-02 16:04:42.273  T0       Y       90
BLACK     ERMA    10-0054  2011-10-06  2010-02-02 16:23:11.193  T1c      Y       91
BROWN     VERSIE  07-0455  2011-09-22  2007-10-17 15:19:10.330  0(is)    Y       123
BROWN     VERSIE  07-0455  2011-09-22  2009-08-21 12:23:50.980  T2       Y       124
```

Comment: Forgot to attach sample:RO# lname fname fow_visit stage_dt T_Stage surv_status rownum 05-0022 ZHAO XIAN MING 2011-03-30 2005-04-14 14:58:02.650 3 Y 2 05-0023 ZHAO XIAN MING 2011-03-30 2005-04-14 14:58:02.650 3 Y 3 05-0081 BAREFIELD SYBIL 2011-07-20 2008-07-02 11:18:37.950 1c Y 13 05-0081 BAREFIELD SYBIL 2011-07-20 2008-07-02 11:18:37.950 2 Y 14

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
with temp_cte([RO#], [stage_dt])
as
(
    select [RO#], max([stage_dt]) as [stage_dt]
    from temp
    group by [RO#]
)

select temp.*
from temp
join temp_cte on temp_cte.[RO#] = temp.[RO#]
    and temp_cte.[stage_dt] = temp.[stage_dt]
```

There are other ways but I think this is simple.

Comment: THANK you Sam, but I found something else - some stage_dt have dups in same day, hrs, min and some in RO#:

Comment: if that is the case, you could use rank() over partition order by stage_dt, and pick rank() = 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM temp_table 
  WHERE stage_dt IN (SELECT max(stage_dt) FROM temp_table)
```

According to the DB system, the **IN** operator can be replaced by **=** or another operator that suits the DB system.